# Prove: affine transformation maps "line at infinity" to "line at infinity"

Tags: projective-geometry, affine-geometry, projection-matrices, computer-vision

I'm studying Computer Vision and my lecturer stated that:

> The affine transformation maps "line at infinity" to "line at infinity".

I'm trying to prove it as part of my preparation for the final exam. My lecturer suggested to check the points on the line for that. Also in the lecture, it was explained that "line at infinity" is a line of form $I_{\infty}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{T}$ (where $T$ is transpose). So for any ideal point (has $0$ in the third coordinate) $p=\begin{bmatrix}x & y & 0\end{bmatrix}^{T}$:
$$
I_{\infty}^{T}p=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}x & y & 0\end{bmatrix}^{T}=0
$$
It was in the context of projective spaces.

How can I prove the above theorem of Affine transformation that maps "line at infinity" to "line at infinity"? Tried to look online but only found a statement [here](https://judyye.github.io/pdf/notes.pdf) (page 5).

Also, I guess that the definition of "Ideal points" and "line at infinity" are much more broad then the one I got from the lecture, but since I need to stick to those definitions, how one can prove the above statement? (It's Computer Vision course after all)

Comment: We can define the projective plane as the union of the affine plane with the set of directions in the affine plane, where a *direction* is the collection of lines parallel to a given line. We call these directions *points at infinity*. So, all you really need to prove is that affine transformations map parallel lines to parallel lines.

Comment: A correct way to express it is : Each time you take out **any** line from the projective plane, you get a specific "affine space". Speaking about "the" line at infinity can be considered as an abuse of language: it is because you have taken a certain system of coordinates that the "the" can be acceptable, but any other line would do the job with adapted coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Mo Pol Bol's comment is comprehensive and effective. Here I just want to highlight the theory behind that comment, if that can shed more light on the situation in general.

Let ${\cal A}(E)$ be an affine space over the $K$-vector space $E$ (where $K$ is a field).

The canonical projective extension of ${\cal A}(E)$ is the projective space ${\cal P} (E\times K)$. The function

$$ J = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
{\cal A}(E) & \longrightarrow & {\cal P}(E\times K)\\[1ex]
P & \longmapsto & [P-O,1]
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
where $O$ is any fixed point of ${\cal A}(E)$, and $[P-O,1]$ is an abbreviation for $\langle(P-O,1)\rangle$, is an *immersion* of ${\cal A}(E)$ into ${\cal P}(E\times K)$. The set

$$ l_\infty := {\cal P}(E\times K) \setminus J({\cal A}(E)) $$
is an hyperplane of ${\cal P}(E\times K)$, called *the improper hyperplane* or *the hyperplane at infinity* of ${\cal A}(E)$. Obviously it is a *line* if the affine space is an affine plane.

It is easy to see that

$$ l_\infty = \{[a,0]\;\;:\;\;a\in E, \;a\neq 0\}. $$

Each affinity $f : {\cal A}(E) \longrightarrow {\cal A}(E)$ extends to a projectivity $\tilde f :{\cal P}(E\times K) \longrightarrow {\cal P}(E\times K)$:

$$ \tilde f([a,t]) = [df(a), t] \qquad\qquad \big(a\in E,\;t\in K,\; (a,t)\neq(0,0)\big), $$

where $df$ is the *linear part* of $f$. $\big[$Remember that a function $f : {\cal A}(E) \rightarrow {\cal A}(E)$ is *affine* iff there is a *linear function* $L : E\rightarrow E$ such that $f(P)-f(Q)=L(P-Q)$ for all $P,Q\in {\cal A}(E)$. We denote $L$ by $df.\big]$

Now the conclusion is almost obvious:

$$ \tilde f([a,0]) = [df(a),0]\qquad\qquad \forall\,a\neq0 $$

so

$$ \tilde f(l_\infty) = l_\infty $$

because $df$ is bijective, being $f$ an affinity.